# How to resolve an url by fetch & redirect without refresh with react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, service-worker

I need to fetch the current url in my react application because our front/nginx may respond with a redirect which won't be hit if user has the service-worker active..

therefor I currently have this logic in my 404 component on didMount.

```
fetch('/test/page/xxxx/', {redirect: 'follow'}).then(res => {
  if(res.status === 200 && res.redirected) {
    console.log(res)
    // this.props.push(res.url)
    // window.location.replace(res.url)
    // window.location.hash = res.url
    console.log('Redirected to ' + res.url)
  }
})
```

the res.url that I get back in the respons is a full url ex: https://example.net/xxx/xxx/xxxx which makes it hard for me to use push from react-router-redux because it expects a relative url. Can anyone help me with a regex that can get the slugs from the res.url or does anyone have any other idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the `URL` interface <sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)</sup> available in the `window` that can be used create a URL object.

A `URL` object has the `pathname` property that is used to retrieve the path component of the URL.

```
this.props.push(
  new URL(res.url).pathname
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Really saved my sunday-headache!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the pathname (relative URL) is by parsing it with the [URL interface API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
const { pathname } = new URL("https://example.net/aaa/bbb/ccc");
console.log(pathname) // "/aaa/bbb/ccc"
```

In the context of your code

```
fetch("/test/page/xxxx/", { redirect: "follow" }).then(res => {
  if(res.status === 200 && res.redirected) {
    const { pathname } = new URL(res.url);
    this.props.push(pathname);
  }
});
```

NOTE: Not supported in IE11 and below. If support for that browser is needed, there is a polyfill https://github.com/lifaon74/url-polyfill

There is also a [proposal](https://github.com/jasnell/proposal-url) to be added to babel, expected soon to be a stage 0 feature

Comment: Thanks alot! Really saved my sunday-headache!